# how could I change a list of tuples with digits into a list of numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am stuck in this part of coding. 
I have a list looks like this:
`list = [(4, 7, 5), (4, 5, 7), (7, 4, 5), (7, 5, 4), (5, 4, 7), (5, 7, 4)]` 
and I want to change it to something looks like this:

```
new_list = [475,457,745,754,547,574]
```

how do I do that? TIA.

Comment: Since your tuples are of a fixed size, you could just use maths: `[t[0] * 100 + t[1] * 10 + t[2] for t in inputlist]`. Or use strings: `[int(''.join(map(str, t))) for t in inputlist]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the tuples into a string and then use `int` to convert the strings into numbers:

```
l = [(4, 7, 5), (4, 5, 7), (7, 4, 5), (7, 5, 4), (5, 4, 7), (5, 7, 4)]

result = [int(''.join(map(str, t))) for t in l]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[475, 457, 745, 754, 547, 574]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. No wonder! I didn't add map in my code.  Even though I learn a little bit about map, sometimes I still don't know how to use it.